# I am not going to bond my life with

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Is it possible to say I am not going to bond my life with... ?
I have not found examples where "Bond" would used with a noun between BOND and WITH.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to say that.  You cannot bond steel with steel using wood glue.  I am not going to bond my life with {someone else's life}.

Comment: It's idiomatically unlikely a native speaker would use ***bond with*** for what I imagine is your intended meaning. Far more common would be something like [*(I don't want) **to tie my life to** (a struggling artist).*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+tie+my+life+to%22) Note that ***to bond with X*** has a well-established idiomatic/metaphoric sense *(to form a close personal relationship with person X),* which is probably part of the reason it doesn't work well in the context of *bonding one's **life** with X*.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever weird reason, it is idiomatic to talk about a **bond** (noun) between one person and another:

> The *bonds* of matrimony should not easily be broken
>
> They had made between them an unshakable *bond*, to protect each other unto death.

but it is not as common to talk about **bonding** (verb) your life with another's.   This isn't to say you *can't* do it, but it should be a deliberate play on words:

> They say the bonds of matrimony are not easily broken, so I don't plan to *bond* myself with anyone until I'm good and ready.

"Bond with" is fine, but it may be more natural to use "bond **to**":

> The two young friends were **bonded to** each other as if glued -- they went everywhere and did everything together.

Comment: I still think ***tie*** is more natural in most contexts, but your third example would usually be *I don't plan to **bind** myself **to** anyone...*